# Best Framework for javascript /UI EXTJS vs HTML 5 vs other frameworks

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, javascript-framework

We have a application build on flex framework , which enjoys quite flashy look and feel features , due to prequisites of flash , user wanted to have an alternate framework , which does not have client machine dependency.

The application was freshly built on ExtJS 3.3 , it also enjoyed flashy look and feel features , but soon we faced issues with respect to performance and customizing the behaviour of the ExtJS application.

Now we are really in delima to continue with the Existing ExtJS application , or building the application from scratch on pure html , dhtml , HTML5 etc , where we can customize the components in our way with performance.

Please share what would be best framework with respect to

1.Performance
2.Customization flexibility
3.Maintenance

Edit1# after doing a lot of research, meeting people who are working on various JavaScript frameworks and working on the real scenarios where the difference actually comes in to picture, below is my research

```
ExtJS

1.  ExtJS (The latest version) is a MVC based framework based on Yahoo YUI, it supports the     concepts of MVC in JavaScript and is a well tiered framework with good extendibility and support.
2.  ExtJS has good documentation and active forums.
3.  It comes in both paid and free version , offers paid support also.
4.  ExtJS 4.x has got a major revamp from design perspective and improved in terms of performance 
5.  To be comfortable in Extjs , if is required to have a good knowledge of JavaScript 
6.  If you have to use a good MVC framework in enterprise application use ExtJS 
7.  There is greater learning curve in case of ExtJS


jQuery

1.  jQuery provides a good library with css based selectors promoted by Microsoft
2.  jQuery also has good documentation and forum support
3.  jQuery is open source ,you can make your own plugins and contribute
4.  jQuery is quite lighter and fast in terms of performance .It does not follow the MVC framework , the code sometimes appears cluttered when really complex.
5.  jQuery is easy to understand as it is based on css selectors , follows the rules like css (quite similar)
6.  For common tasks in JavaScript it is the most suitable framework, well suitable for ASAP projects.
7.  The learning curve is not that big, it is quiet easy to grasp, even in case of novice developers.
```

Please feel free to add details , if i missed something
Thanks
Abhi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing beats pure Javascript. However there are a few good frameworks out there that will help you write good, manageable code.

Dojo - http://dojotoolkit.org/ It seems to be a robust framework for building large scale apps. Has all the fancy things to help you manage your codebase and a UI framework.

Requirejs - Just a good way to separate your code into reusable modules and load them as required. Helps in managing your code.

Backbone.js - A good library to manage your javascript data. Client side MVC-ish style of framework. Has the ability to sync with your server. Very extensible.

Underscore.js - A good library to manipulate javascript data. Has all of the fancy functions.

Jquery - A good dom manipulation library with a good ajax library and a few other nifty things. Great and popular library with many plugins and a simple plugin system.

Jquery UI - Works great with Jquery, lots of widgets.

Now it really depends on what sort of a client you have. If you need IE6 support, use Dojo UI library or Jquery UI. If you only need to support chrome & firefox & latest version of IE, you are usually better off with writing your own widgets (tabs, popups etc are all actually very simple widgets that can be implemented in 20 lines of code).

Answer (score 5):

I think Use http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ it has good documentation and JS library built in- and you can also use other js library  while using this and customization as you want

Answer (score 1):

You may check the [dhtmlx](http://dhtmlx.com) library (free for open source). It offers a set of customizable UI widgets which can work reasonably fast with the large sets of data (due to dynamic loading, smart rendering, and other techniques that enhance performance).

(disclaimer: I work at dhtmlx)